# Create a SO library for math functions in linux using C in vscode

Tags: c, linux, makefile, terminal, shared-libraries

The project structure:

```
project_root/
    ├── headers/
    │   ├── math_functions.h
    ├── src/
    │   ├── math_functions.c
    │   ├── main.c
```

Now, Create a SO library and execute the program and print the output.
The math_functions.c contain sqrt,floor,ceil,power functions.
Kindly help me with this question.

I am a newbie✌️

This is how I gave the code:
**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "math_functions.h"

int main() 
{
    double num = 16.0;

    printf("Square root of %.2lf: %.2lf\n", num, custom_sqrt(num));
    printf("Ceil of %.2lf: %.2lf\n", num, custom_ceil(num));
    printf("Floor of %.2lf: %.2lf\n", num, custom_floor(num));

    double base = 2.0;
    double exponent = 3.0;
    printf("%.2lf raised to the power of %.2lf: %.2lf\n", base, exponent, custom_power(base, exponent));

    return 0;
}
```

**math_functions.c**

```
#include <math.h>

#include "math_functions.h"

double custom_sqrt(double x) 
{
    return sqrt(x);
}

double custom_ceil(double x) 
{
    return ceil(x);
}

double custom_floor(double x) 
{
    return floor(x);
}

double custom_power(double base, double exponent) 
{
     return pow(base, exponent);
}
```

**math_functions.h**

```
#define MATH_FUNCTIONS_H

// Function prototypes

double custom_sqrt(double x);

double custom_ceil(double x);

double custom_floor(double x);

double custom_power(double base, double exponent);

#endif // MATH_FUNCTIONS_H
```

Now, tell me how to compile or how to make the makefile. As I am getting errors while compiling and for make commands and **your text** is not created
Please correct me if this is wrong, Also please give me the right way to do✌️✌️

Comment: "Now, tell me how to compile or how to make the makefile. As I am getting errors while compiling..." I'm sorry but that's not really how this site works. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it (like telling us how ***you*** build, and what errors you get).

Comment: Agreed, edit you question to show the exact cmds you execute and the exact text of the "reply/error" from the system. Good luck.

Comment: You can't have two `main` functions in a C program, so your library won't be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

To Compile the .c file and then generate into a .so file.

1. gcc -c math_functions.c -o math_functions.o
2. gcc -shared -fPIC math_functions.o -o libmath_functions.so
3. Generate the executable file. (reference to .so file)

   gcc -o main main.c libmath_functions.so

   ```
    or
   ```

   gcc -o main main.c -lmath_functions -L.
4. Check your "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" before executing ./main

You could learn how to write a Makefile to do these procedures.

Comment: Thanks, it created .o and .so file. But, I am getting this error for generating executable file.
 $ gcc -o main src/main.c -Imath_functions -L. 
Error:
/usr/bin/ld: ./libmath_functions.so: undefined reference to ceil' 
/usr/bin/ld: ./libmath_functions.so: undefined reference to 'pow' 
/usr/bin/ld: ./libmath_functions.so: undefined reference to "sqrt' 
/usr/bin/ld: ./libmath_functions.so: undefined reference to 'floor'
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.
 Can you tell me what I am missing here. Thanks

Comment: undefined reference to "sqrt', 'pow', 'ceil' ..., they all are the standard math library.
So please check your library path is correct or not.  Follow the document, it also need to add "-lm".  (library math).
"Link with -lm": gcc -o main main.c -lmath_functions -lm -L.
Example: https://linux.die.net/man/3/pow